# Making a border around a translucent shape in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

The recommended method for making a border around a shape using LibGdx is to draw a larger version of the shape to serve as the border, then draw the shape over the larger image.

```
shapeRenderer.setColor(borderColor);
shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius + borderWidth);
shapeRenderer.setColor(shapeColor);
shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);
```

This works well most of the time, but if you want `shapeColor` to have any opacity less than 1, it fails.  The problem is that you can see the `borderColor` through the shape, and the colors are blended.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is to draw the border as a line with a thickness first, then draw the inner part of the circle as a filled shape;

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line)
Gdx.gl10.glLineWidht(borderWidth);
shapeRenderer.setColor(borderColor);
shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius + borderWidth);
shapeRenderer.end();

shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled)
shapeRenderer.setColor(shapeColor);
shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

You might have to query for the capabilities for the line width using `glGet` and asking for 'GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE' and 'GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE' ([opengl reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGet.xml)), and it will possibly make the drawing device dependent.

If that does not work, you could try render to texture first, using a frame buffer with no blending, then draw that buffer (with blending) to screen;

```
// Position and size of circle, and border
float circleX = 100; 
float circleY = 100;

float radius=100;
float border=10;

// Total size of the buffer
int size = (int)((radius+border)*2);

// Create the buffer and get a region to it
FrameBuffer buffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, size, size, false);
TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
region.flip(false, true); 

// Begin the buffer, any draw calls made after this affect the buffer, not the "screen"
buffer.begin();
ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
// Draw border, centered on buffer
renderer.setColor(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1.0f)
renderer.circle(size / 2, size / 2, radius + border);

// Draw center, centered on buffer
renderer.setColor(new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5f)
renderer.circle(size / 2, size / 2, radius);

renderer.end(); // shapes done
buffer.end(); // buffer done

// Now render the buffer onto the "screen"
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
batch.begin();
// Move to the buffer offset representing the circle's position
batch.draw(region, circleX - size, circleY - size);
batch.end();
```

Obviously, in the example above, try to new up the `buffer`, `region`, and `renderer` outside of your render method so that you don't pay the performance penalty of doing that every time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't want to rely on this if possible because of the line width limitations you mentioned.  I think I may have to go with some sort of special blending but I'm not sure what to use since I'm not too familiar with OpenGL.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. I've added an explanation for my other suggestion where you render to buffer first.